# Why this two very short code are not equivalent? (yield, generators)

Tags: python

Here is my code:

**Version 1**

```
def X():
    while True:
        pos = something.find("xxx")
        if pos != -1:
            yield pos
        break
```

**Version 2**

```
def X():
    while True:
        pos = something.find("xxx")
        if pos == -1:
            break
        yield pos
```

Version 1 only gave me 1 result, while version 2 gave me all results! WTF?

Comment: They do entirely different things. the first loop always breaks after the first iteration.

Comment: do you know what `break` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 1, you are breaking the loop immediately (and unconditionally) at the end of the first iteration.

In version 2, you are breaking the loop only when it fails to find the string `"xxx"`.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are generator function but in version 1, it checks for position and compare it with -1 and if its satisfies the condition it yields the result otherwise it breaks the loop.

```
def X():
    while True:
        pos = something.find("xxx")
        if pos != -1:
            yield pos
        break
```

while in version 2 , it keeps yielding the result till it reaches the end of file -1 or get -1 as value of pos.

```
def X():
    while True:
        pos = something.find("xxx")
        if pos == -1:
            break
        yield pos
```